# How do I correct error message while coding

Tags: python-3.x, sqlite

I am using Linux Mint. When I write following code I get error "table books has no column named year" message:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
connection.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                title TEXT,
                author TEXT,
                year INTEGER,
                Remks   TEXT
                )
                ''')
books_data =[
    ("Hunt for Red October", "ABC", 1999,"Good"),
    ("The Monk who sold his Ferrari","DEF",1957,"Excellent"),
    ("Python for Beginners", "GHI",1987,"Standard"),
    ("Learn Python", "KLM", 1857,"Below Par")

]
connection.executemany('INSERT INTO books (title, author, year, Remks) VALUES         (?,?,?)',books_data)
result = connection.execute('SELECT * FROM books')
data = result.fetchall()
for row in data:
    print(f'Title: {row[1]}')
    print(f'Author: {row[2]}')
    print(f'Year: {row[3]}')
    print('')
connection.commit()`

connection.close()
```

I tried deleting and re-writing the code again but to no avail

Comment: Code as shown works except for the backtick on the 2nd-to-last line and need 4 question marks `(?,?,?,?)` in the `executemany`. Both errors were different than the stated error. Please make sure the code posted when copied and run **without changes** produces the error you see.

Comment: `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS` is always a red flag. I bet your database has a different definition of the table than the one shown.

Comment: I've tried both the things, but the problem is persistent

Answer (score 1):

I made some corrections. You need a curser, too. Read also the doc for Datatypes [2.2](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html):

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('mydatabase.db')
cur = connection.cursor()
cur.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS books(
                id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                title TEXT,
                author TEXT,
                year TEXT,
                remark TEXT);
                ''')
books_data =[
    ("Hunt for Red October", "ABC", "1999","Good"),
    ("The Monk who sold his Ferrari","DEF","1957","Excellent"),
    ("Python for Beginners", "GHI","1987","Standard"),
    ("Learn Python", "KLM", "1857","Below Par")]

sql = 'INSERT INTO books (title, author, year, remark) VALUES (?,?,?,?);'
cur.executemany(sql, books_data)
connection.commit()

for row in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM books'):
    print(row)
    
connection.close()
```

Output:

```
(1, 'Hunt for Red October', 'ABC', '1999', 'Good')
(2, 'The Monk who sold his Ferrari', 'DEF', '1957', 'Excellent')
(3, 'Python for Beginners', 'GHI', '1987', 'Standard')
(4, 'Learn Python', 'KLM', '1857', 'Below Par')
(5, 'Hunt for Red October', 'ABC', '1999', 'Good')
(6, 'The Monk who sold his Ferrari', 'DEF', '1957', 'Excellent')
(7, 'Python for Beginners', 'GHI', '1987', 'Standard')
(8, 'Learn Python', 'KLM', '1857', 'Below Par')
```